# Can the Translation Workbench "Out of Date" values be accessed via the Metadata API?

Tags: metadata-api, translation-workbench

When you're updating terms in the Translation Workbench there is a column indicating that the current translation is out of date. What mechanism in Salesforce checks these translations? Does it happen upon updating a picklist or field label behind the scenes? Can I programatically access a Salesforce API to see which terms are out of date?

Ideally, I would like to have a notification go to a translator when someone updates a term in the workbench so that they know they need to go update a translation.

Documentation here on using the `Out of Date` field does not refer to any APIs or means of accessing this value outside of Translation Workbench in Setup: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=updating_translated_terms.htm&type=5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there isn't any API access to Translation Workbench data, but the idea has been posted to [success.salesforce.com](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BqyL).